# Error while accessing Rest services com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException

Tags: java, json, web-services, rest, jar

I am using the Jersey API for the web services. I am sending the multipart data and getting an exception when the client is trying to connect to webservices.
Please help me fix this issue.

Webservices is a third party, so I cannot change anything. Below is the client code

```
Client client = Client.create();
WebResource webResource = client.resource("<<webservice URL>>");
ClientResponse response1 =webResource.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(ClientResponse.class, js);
```

It returns this exception:

```
<===== exception
======> com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException
```

Jars added are:

```
jersey-client-1.9.jar
jersey-server.19.1.jar
jersey-core-1.9.jar
jersey-json-1.9.jar
jersey-bundled-1.9.jar
jersey-multipart.jar
mimepull-1.9.jar
```

Am I missing anything? Please let me know.

Comment: Could you please post some more of your code?

Comment: As i already told you webservices are provided by third party. Have only url to access it. Already given  client code.                                                                                          please let me know what actually u need